# Is there a better way to create a screenshot in phantomjs?

Tags: ajax, phantomjs, koa

Are There better ways to send pictures to the client?

base64 is so slow.

Here is the github

https://github.com/abnerCrack/screenshot

> server

```
    exec("phantomjs screen.js " + this.query.url + " " + this.query.width + " " + this.query.width,options,function (error, stdout, stderr) {
        if(error) console.log("Error:", error);
        callback(null, "data:image/png;base64," + stdout);
        console.log(stdout,stderr)
    });

}
// response
app.route('/query')
  .get(function * (next) {
    console.log("query", this.query);
    this.body = yield screenshot;
  });
```

> screen.js

```
page.onLoadFinished = function(status) {

  var base64 = page.renderBase64('JPEG');
    if (status !== 'success') {
    console.log('request fail');
  } else {
  console.log(base64);
  }
  phantom.exit();
};
page.open(args[1]);
```

Comment: I can't measure a significant difference in rendering between `page.render` and `page.renderBase64` with PhantomJS 2.0. How long does a screenshot take? Have you taken the time into account that the page has to be loaded?

Comment: I could not find a good method to deal with the problem.  dont have a good method to  measurement  the time

Comment: To answer your question: I don't think there are better ways to render somehing.